# Got no credit for writing a square root with index

Tags: algebra-precalculus

On a quiz, I was asked to rewrite an expression as a radical. I wrote the square root with a $2$ in the index, but I received no credit. Is it completely wrong to write the $2$ even though usually you don't?

Question: Rewrite $(5x)^{3/2}$ in radical form. I wrote $(\sqrt[2]{5x})^3$.

Comment: You should include the expression in your question.

Comment: I think we need the whole question and the whole answer before we can help. Please [edit] the question to provide that.

Comment: Maybe you missed the points because the rest of your answer is wrong? Without seeing what you’ve written or the original question, we cannot help at all. (Even seeing them, we can’t magically give your points back, either. It ultimately rests upon your TA or Professor).

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: It's probable that the expected answer is $5x\sqrt{5x}.$

Comment: I agree with the cheerful parsnip. I think *radical form* probably has a particular meaning (or has been used in a particular manner) in your class.

Comment: Thank you that is helpful